# Find an array slice equaling sum

Tags: python

I would like to be reviewed on efficiency, style, and obviously if there is a bug I would like to know.

```
def findsum(a, n):
  ''' Find whether a consecutive array slice sums up to n '''
  for i in range(len(a)):
    j = i + 1
    while j <= len(a):
      if sum(a[i:j]) == n:
        return True
      j += 1
  return False
```

Answer (score 6):

1. There's a bug:

   ```
   >>> a = [1, 2, 3]
   >>> findsum(a, 0)
   False
   ```

   but the result should be `True` because the consecutive slice `a[0:0]` sums to zero.
2. The docstring could be clearer. "a consecutive array slice" — of which array? Presumably the parameter `a` is meant, but it is best to be explicit. Similarly, "Find whether" — and then what? The docstring should say what value is returned.
3. The function has runtime \$Θ(n^3)\$. That's because `sum(a[i:j])` takes an unnecessary copy of the slice, and because it sums it starting at the beginning of the slice. But if you maintained a running sum, then the runtime would come down to \$Θ(n^2)\$. That's easy to implement using [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) and  [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

   ```
   from itertools import accumulate, islice

   def findsum(a, n):
       """Return True if any consecutive slice of the sequence a sums to n,
       False if none do.

       """
       return n == 0 or any(total == n
                            for i in range(len(a))
                            for total in accumulate(islice(a, i, None)))
   ```